# Фильтр данных при запросе через fetch

Tags: массивы, api, fetch

Я только начала осваивать js. Сейчас прохожу promises. Задача такова: Нужно сделать запрос к серверу и получить данные с url. Там представлен массив  содержащий в себе объекты с данными о пользователях. Мне нужно вывести только фамилии пользователей.
Запрос я вроде написала и он срабатывает, а вот вывести фамилии никак не получается. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем моя ошибка?

```
let delay = ms =>{
 return new Promise (resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms))
}

const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?=per_page';

function fetchRequest(){
  console.log('Делаем запрос на получение данных по 12 пользователям')
  return delay(1000).then(() =>{
    return fetch(url);
  }).then(response => response.json())
}

fetchRequest()
.then(data => {
  console.log('Data:', data);

let usersLastName = data.reduce((item) => {
   return item.last_name;
},{})

console.log ('Фамилии всех 12 пользователей', usersLastName);
})

.catch (e => console.error(e));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать `map`, а не `reduce`

И помимо полученного ответа надо **еще раз** написать `.data`, т.к. массив с пользователями лежит именно по этому ключу

```
fetchRequest()
.then(response => {
    let usersLastNames = response.data.map(item => item.last_name);
                              // ^^^^^
    console.log ('Фамилии всех 12 пользователей', usersLastNames );
})
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!)

Comment: а если нужно к примеру отфильтровать фамилии начинающиеся на F, то лучше через startsWith делать?

Comment: фильтрация - `filter` и `startsWith`  да

Comment: еще раз спасибо)

Comment: галочку рядом с ответом тык!)

Comment: ок, поставила) я тут еще только осваиваюсь))